# Запрос с конструкцией IN

Tags: sql

Всем доброго времени
Задача такая - Return all employes which are CLERKs from A00 department, MANAGERs from C01 and CLERKs from D21 using once IN predicate - главное сделать с предикатом IN и что бы он использовался только один раз в запросе
Вот мой запрос, но его нужно преобразовать в конструкцию с IN, пока что не понимаю как это должно выглядеть

```
SELECT firstnme, workdept, job
FROM employee
WHERE (workdept = 'A00' AND job = 'CLERK')
        OR (workdept = 'C01' AND job = 'MANAGER')
        OR (workdept = 'D21' AND job = 'CLERK')
```

Comment: Используй ROW constructor. `.. WHERE (workdept, job) IN (('C01', 'MANAGER'), ..) .. `

Comment: @Akina походу у меня что от не так с синтаксисом?
SELECT firstnme
FROM employee
WHERE (workdept, job) IN (('A00', 'CLERK'), ('C01', 'MANAGER'), ('D21', 'CLERK'))

Comment: Разобрался - слово values пропустил. Спасибо